# GCP Compute - RDP alternative?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm obviously new to GCP and am testing new Compute VMs, particularly Windows 2016 VM. 
I have firewall rules established to RDP to it but am concerned about a possible few scenarios:

1. What if the IP of the VM changes, can I keep it the same IP? Is it a Google IP and gateway, or if I'm hybrid is there a way to configure the VM to be on an IP on our network with our gateway?
2. If I both the IP settings, how do I reset the server back to DHCP? Is there a local console I can connect to the VM with and how could I do so?

Answer (score 0):

If you create windows Compute VMs, then by default it assigned an internal ip and external IP from Google, you have an option to create with just the internal IP using the gcloud command [1](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) `gcloud compute instances create` and the flag `no-address`.

Static internal IPs provide the ability to reserve internal IP addresses from the private RFC 1918 IP range configured in your subnet, then assign those reserved internal addresses to resources as needed check [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address).

How to do it:

> You can reserve a static internal IP address before creating the
>   associated resource, or you can create the resource with an ephemeral
>   internal IP address and then promote that ephemeral IP address to a
>   static internal IP address.

You can delete a static internal IP address if you no longer need it. whenever is being used or not, if it being used, it remains attached to the resource until the resource is deleted, in which case, the address is returned to the pool of available addresses for other projects.

For External IP, it's the same thing as internal IP, When you create a VM instance, it is automatically assigned an ephemeral external IP address (if you didn't use the flag and the gcloud command). If you don't want an ephemeral external IP address, you can explicitly assign a static external IP address to the instance instead.

You can reserve two types of external IP addresses:

> - A regional IP address which can be used by VM instances with one or more network interfaces or by Network load balancers.
> - A global IP address which can be used for global load balancers: HTTP(S), SSL proxy, and TCP proxy.

You have more flexibility for the external IP:

> - You can assigning a static external IP address to a new VM instance.
> - You can change or assign an external IP address to an existing instance.
> - You can promote an ephemeral external IP address.

Regarding your question:

What if the IP of the VM changes, can I keep it the same IP? Is it a Google IP and gateway, or if I'm hybrid is there a way to configure the VM to be on an IP on our network with our gateway?

Your internal IP will not change, unless if you delete your instance and recreate it, even if you stop it will keep the internal IP. As I mention above you can keep the same internal IP after reserving it.
The internal IP belong to your [VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc) in your project in Google Cloud Platform.

You can specify an internal IP address using the gcloud command-line tool or the API with the flag `--private-network-ip`.

gcloud compute instances create [INSTANCE_NAME] --private-network-ip [IP_ADDRESS]

Not sue what do you mean by "to configure the VM to be on an IP on our network with our gateway?" if you refer to use a network outside you VPC network in  Google Cloud, I don't think this can be done.

If I both the IP settings, how do I reset the server back to DHCP? Is there a local console I can connect to the VM with and how could I do so?

For internal IP, you can not reset the IP unless if you delete the instance, for external IP you can remove it whatever you want, check [this section](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#unassign_ip)
beside your Google Cloud dashboard, you can interact with the [Serial Console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console)

Comment: So if somebody logs into the Windows VM in Google and goes to network properties, and changes the IP from DHCP to static, and sets the wrong DNS server, subnet and gateway and clicks OK, what would I be able to do to resolve it then? Because RDP is now no longer an option. I've been digging through Gloud command reference and am still not clear on what I could do in this situation to revert the settings.

Comment: Although this would be an extreme case, you can always follow the [RDP troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-rdp) guide and run [start-up scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) which may help.

Comment: If someone performed those steps, the instance becomes unusable. The instance can no longer communicate with the metadata server nor the rest of the network. Your only option is to create a new instance. You can use [snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) to backup and transfer your data